# How to import i18next in React Native?

Tags: react-native, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to use react-i18next in a React Native app. When importing i18next at the top of my index.js or app.tsx file, the build crashes with this error:

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

Here is the code:

index.js:

```js
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import "i18n/index";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

i18/index.ts:

```js
import i18n, { LanguageDetectorAsyncModule } from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { Platform, NativeModules } from "react-native";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import en from "./en.json";
import fr from "./fr.json";

const languages = {
  EN: "en",
  FR: "fr",
};

const resources = {
  en: { translation: en },
  fr: { translation: fr },
};

const detectLocale = () => {
  const storedLocale = AsyncStorage.getItem("locale");
  if (storedLocale) {
    return storedLocale;
  }
  const mobileLocale =
    Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
        NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
      : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
  if (mobileLocale) {
    return mobileLocale;
  }
  return languages.EN;
};

const LanguageDetector = {
  type: "languageDetector" as LanguageDetectorAsyncModule["type"],
  async: false,
  init: () => {},
  detect: detectLocale,
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

export default i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: languages.EN,
    keySeparator: ".",
    whitelist: [languages.EN, languages.FR],
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try rerunning metro bundler and make sure there isn't another metro bundler running for another react native application.

Comment: Hi, there is only one metro process running, and I relaunched it of course.